# Getting error on root draw Check the render method of `MapViewDirections`

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps, direction, map-directions

I am working on react native map , I am use "react-native-maps-directions": "^1.8.0",  for draw a root on map .  i am doing simple Load MapView and  maps-direction npm .
Pls review code tell me what i am doing wrong in code

let me know Thank  you.

**1. This is a code tsx class.**

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {View} from 'react-native';
import MapView from 'react-native-maps';
import style from './style';
import MapViewDirections  from 'react-native-maps-directions';

const MapCls = () => {
  const [coordinates] = useState([
    {
      latitude: 48.8587741,
      longitude: 2.2069771,
    },
    {
      latitude: 48.8323785,
      longitude: 2.3361663,
    },
  ]);

  return (
    <View>
      <MapView
        style={style.map}
        showsUserLocation={true}
        showsBuildings={true}
        zoomEnabled={true}
        showsMyLocationButton={true}
        onMapReady={() => {}}>
        <MapViewDirections
          origin={coordinates[0]}
          destination={coordinates[1]}
          apikey={'give key here xyz.....'}
        />
      </MapView>
    </View>
  );
};
export default MapCls;

**2. Package.json class**
```

```js
{
  "name": "firstapp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-native": "0.68.2",
    "react-native-maps": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-maps-directions": "^1.8.0",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.15",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.69.3",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.67.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.2"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}


**3. Console Error**
```

```html
**I am getting this error from :**

****Running "firstapp" with {"rootTag":1}
 ERROR  Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.****


**ERROR  Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.***

   Check the render method of `MapViewDirections`.
```

Comment: Check this one : https://github.com/bramus/react-native-maps-directions/issues/195#issuecomment-1180551518

Comment: Link suggested polyline Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error , but i just forgout to install react native direction

"npm install react-native-maps-directions"